# PHPUnit: Class not found

Tags: php, testing, phpunit

I use PHPUnit 5.7.23 in my class Compte, I develop this code in a method

```
   /**
     * @covers Compte::method()
     * @dataProvider entityToJsonData
     */
    public function testMethod($data, $expected)
    {
        $this->object = $this->getMockBuilder('Compte')
            ->getMock();

        $actualReponse = $this->object->method($data);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $actualReponse);

    }
```

PHP display this error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Compte' not found in CompteTest.php

Can you help me ?

Comment: You need to provide the namespace as well, ex: `Namespace\Namespace2\Compte`

Comment: Are you registering an autoloader in your PHPUnit bootstrapping code?

Comment: Use Namespaces as described by @ka_lin

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Namespaces:

```
$this->object = $this->getMockBuilder('<Vendor>\<Component>\Compte')
        ->getMock();
```

Alternatively, you can also use an already visible class ('use' statement above the class declaration) such as follows:

```
<?php
use <Vendor>\<Component>\Compte;

class MyClassTest extends TestCase 
{
...
    public function testMethod($data, $expected)
    {
        $this->object = $this->getMockBuilder(Compte::class)
            ->getMock();
        ...
    }
...
}
```

`Compte::class` returns the class name including its namespace.

Comment: I developped like your code, but, it displayed the error message